# How to add Mark as private to WordPress Admin Bar for Posts

Tags: admin-bar

I want to add a "Mark as private" or "Make it private" menu to WordPress Admin Bar in front-end. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything?

Comment: I have googled about it but only found how to add "Move to Trash" menu to the admin bar.